# Brown water after shutoff to building plumbing

Tags: plumbing

The cold water valve to several apartments in an old condominium was shut and later re-opened at which point a lot of dirty water came out of the toilet and faucets.  No work was done as it was just a test.  What caused that?

Comment: Probably being shutoff and turned on loosen sediments in the pipes.  Running water for a time should clear it up.

Comment: Yah, that's normal. You could even do it on purpose a bunch of time to clear sediment from the lines. It's just small bits of rust and sand that end up in the water, and settle out and land on the pipes.

Comment: do you mean sediment attached to the valve?  otherwise, why would it be disturbed?